# openssl installation error-NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\MinGW\bin\nasm.EXE' : return code '0x3'

Tags: openssl, nasm, nmake

I'm trying to set up openssl for my windows 10 system. when I run the nmake command as mentioned in the installation process here: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/NOTES-Windows.txt

I'm getting the below error:

nasm  -Ox -f win64 -DNEAR -g -o crypto\rc4\rc4-x86_64.obj "crypto\rc4\rc4-x86_64.asm"
panic: crypto\rc4\rc4-x86_64.asm: assertion cv8_state.source_files != NULL failed at output/codeview.c:513
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\MinGW\bin\nasm.EXE' : return code '0x3'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

can someone please tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: This is just a file not being found. Do you have sais files in the paths shown ?

Comment: Hi yes you are right, some files were  missing..I downloaded the openssl library from here: https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.1.1/   I deleted this one and I again cloned the latest version from their git repository that solved the problem.